# Questions that say "I'm looking for a degree program that meets requirements X,Y,Z"

Tags: discussion

We've recently had a few questions that say, "Does anyone know of a degree program that meets requirements X,Y,Z."

For example, [Where can I take online MBA courses without being admitted?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18289/where-can-i-take-online-mba-courses-without-being-admitted):

> Next year I will enroll in a full time MBA program. Until then, I would like to take transferable online courses to count towards my degree. I talked with admissions, and they will accept up to 6 credits from an AACSB accredited school. Unfortunately, I cannot find a university that offers individual online MBA courses. Does anyone here have suggestions?

Or [Cheapest online degrees](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18283/cheapest-online-degrees):

> What are the cheapest online degrees in Computer Science?

Or [What is the best way to choose an MBA school for someone in lighting industry?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17667/what-is-the-best-way-to-choose-an-mba-school-for-someone-in-lighting-industry):

> Is there a university MBA programme featured with lighting industry? Or is it just famous for global marketing/management?

It is my feeling that these questions are off-topic, but I don't see a lot of consistency in the reason given for closure, and they sometimes end up being closed for tangential reasons. (In these three examples: "This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about academia," "Questions about problems facing undergraduate students are off-topic," and not closed, respectively).

Are questions in this category off-topic, and if so, is there a canonical reason for closing questions in this category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2/3 don't from our [About](https://academia.stackexchange.com/about) page:

> Don't ask about: [...]
>
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer.

Questions asking about best department to study a given field fell into both. In terms of close votes it is **too broad** or **primarily opinion-based**.

For more general reading, [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) from the StackExchange blog. In particular, polling questions are not seen well.

Also, for recommendations (or even queries - i.e. when there is a list of objective answers, given a set of restrictions), in general it is tricky - see [What should be done with questions asking for game recommendations? - Gaming.SE aka Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations/):

> - Close all game-recs unconditionally as shopping recommendation: 74
> - Allow game-recs that are specific enough (withdrawn): 70
> - Only allow game-recs with accessibility constraints: 42
> - Unconditionally allow them: 41

(That is, initial policy, *Close all game-recs unconditionally as shopping recommendation*, [has been withdrawn](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1493/12106).)

However (IMHO), we should allow questions asking for how to search or ones where there answers are meta (pieces of advice on the search, links to listings/rankings/etc), e.g.:

- [How to search for graduate schools that have Masters in Complexity Science/Complex Systems?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10688/)

Answer (score 3):

Such questions are usually poor fits, but there's not a single canonical reason to reject. For instance, they might be **too specific,** so that they're not applicable to other users or **focused on purely undergraduate institutions**. In both of those cases, the specific reasons listed should be cited as grounds for closing. However, otherwise, it's because list-based questions are a poor fit for the site.

Comment: Isn't the canonical reason to close these questions that they are **too specific**? Essentially, every question that fits the schema "please recommend a program for me based on ZY" is per definition too localized, right?

Comment: A counterexample: "What are the top graduate programs in Computer Science?"